# Why is Foundry VTT renderTemplate() method always returning an empty string?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to development for the Foundry VTT platform and have run into an interesting snag using templates. I have followed the tutorial on Foundry's community site (https://foundryvtt.wiki/en/development/guides/Tabs-and-Templates/Template-Basics) exactly, and then tried implementing an alternative version and both versions are returning an empty string when I call renderTemplate.

Below is my code and the contents of my template file.

My Code:

```
async function displayPrintSheet() {
            const template_file = "templates/print-sheet-template.html"; // file path for the template file, from Data directory        
            loadTemplates([template_file]);
            const data_object = { header: "Handlebars header text.",
                    content: "<em>Handlebars</em> <i>content</i>.",
                    footer: "Handlebars footer text."};
            let rendered_html = await renderTemplate(template_file, data_object);

            console.log("DATA OBJECT:");
            console.log(data_object); // <-- Shows the correct data
            console.log("FILE PATH:");
            console.log(template_file); // <-- Shows the correct file path
            console.log("RENDERED HTML:");
            console.log(rendered_html); // <-- always shows an empty string ("")
            
            let d = new Dialog({
                title: "MyDialogTitle",
                content: rendered_html,
                buttons: {
                    toggle: {
                        icon: '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>',
                        label: "Okay",
                        callback: () => console.log("Okay")
                    },
                },
                default: "toggle"
            });
            d.render(true);
        }
        
        console.log("Print Sheet | Button Pressed!");
        displayPrintSheet();
```

And here is the template file, which is located at the path specified:

```
<!doctype html>

<form>
<b>Fixed header</b><br>
{{header}}
<hr>
Fixed content<br>
{{{content}}}
<hr>
Fixed <em>footer</em><br>
{{footer}}
</form>
```

The dialog box opens correctly but also shows an empty string where there should be the HTML code. I've also tried the following:

1. Tried with both the loadTemplates() call and without it as it was unclear if it was needed.
2. Tried removing the <!doctype html> from the template file just in case it was causing an issue.

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated!